# How to add text above circle?

Tags: html, css

I have created a circle pointing to the next circle with arrow mark. Now I want to add text above the circle like `STEP1, STEP2`.

Below is the code snippet which I have tried

```css
.connected-steps {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%; 
  align-items: center;
}

.step {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.connector {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="connected-steps">
  <div class="step">1</div>
  <div class="connector">></div>
  <div class="step">2</div>
  <div class="connector">></div>
  <div class="step">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a container for each step

```
<div class="container-step">
  <div>text</div>
  <div class="step"></div>
</div>
```

if you want the text to be white, you can move

```
color: white;
```

in the css from .step to .container-step